# scala minecraft forgemod 'gradle runClient' gives runtime exception

Tags: scala, gradle, akka, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to use akka inside my scala based mod.

The when testing using "gradle runClient" it gives errors, best I can tell its missing the akka library at runtime.  I don't see how to add akka library though.

If it helps my project is here: https://github.com/tesract/NilCraft

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

build.grade

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'forge'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = "com.tesract.NilCraft" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
version = "0.1"
archivesBaseName = "NilCraft-MC-1.8"

minecraft {
    version = "1.8-11.14.1.1419"
    runDir = "eclipse"

    // the mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // snapshot_YYYYMMDD   snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable_#            stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not allways work.
    // simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings = "snapshot_20141130"
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"

    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.1.4'

    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'

        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }

    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

gradle runClient

```
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
****************************
 Powered By MCP:             
 http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/   
 Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r, 
 R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
 MCP Data version : snapshot_20141130
****************************
:compileApiJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileApiScala UP-TO-DATE
:processApiResources UP-TO-DATE
:apiClasses UP-TO-DATE
:sourceMainJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:sourceMainScala UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:getVersionJson
:extractUserDev UP-TO-DATE
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:getAssetsIndex
:getAssets
:makeStart SKIPPED
:runClient
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: []
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Running with arguments: [--userProperties, {}, --assetsDir, ~/.gradle/caches/minecraft/assets, --assetIndex, 1.8, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --version, 1.8, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker]
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 8.99.18.1419 for Minecraft 1.8 loading
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_45, running on Mac OS X:x86_64:10.10.3, installed at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [FML]: Managed to load a deobfuscated Minecraft name- we are in a deobfuscated environment. Skipping runtime deobfuscation
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[23:50:57] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[23:50:58] [main/ERROR] [FML]: The binary patch set is missing. Either you are in a development environment, or things are not going to work!
[23:50:58] [main/ERROR] [FML]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing
[23:50:58] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[23:50:58] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[23:50:59] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker
[23:50:59] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[23:50:59] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[23:50:59] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[23:51:00] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Player187
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.2
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraftforge.fml.client.SplashProgress:start:233]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Hi. I'm Minecraft, and I'm a crashaholic.

Time: 6/17/15 11:51 PM
Description: Loading screen debug info

This is just a prompt for computer specs to be printed. THIS IS NOT A ERROR


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.10.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_45, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 253128672 bytes (241 MB) / 385351680 bytes (367 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel Inc.' Version: '2.1 INTEL-10.6.20' Renderer: 'Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine'
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Attempting early MinecraftForge initialization
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: MinecraftForge v11.14.1.1419 Initialized
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Replaced 204 ore recipies
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Preloading CrashReport classes
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Completed early MinecraftForge initialization
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Found 0 mods from the command line. Injecting into mod discoverer
[23:51:03] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Searching ~/Desktop/forge-1.8-11.14.1.1419-src/eclipse/mods for mods
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 4 mods to load
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [mcp, FML, Forge, NilCraft] at CLIENT
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [mcp, FML, Forge, NilCraft] at SERVER
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Mod Loader, FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Forge, FMLFileResourcePack:Nil Craft
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Processing ObjectHolder annotations
[23:51:06] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Found 384 ObjectHolder annotations
[23:51:07] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Configured a dormant chunk cache size of 0
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: =============================================================
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: MOD HAS DIRECT REFERENCE System.exit() THIS IS NOT ALLOWED REROUTING TO FML!
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Offendor: akka/actor/ActorSystemImpl$$anon$2.uncaughtException(Ljava/lang/Thread;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Use FMLCommonHandler.exitJava instead
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: =============================================================
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: =============================================================
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: MOD HAS DIRECT REFERENCE System.exit() THIS IS NOT ALLOWED REROUTING TO FML!
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Offendor: akka/actor/ActorSystemImpl$$anon$2.uncaughtException(Ljava/lang/Thread;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Use FMLCommonHandler.exitJava instead
[23:51:08] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: =============================================================
[23:51:08] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Applying holder lookups
[23:51:08] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[23:51:08] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Fatal errors were detected during the transition from PREINITIALIZATION to INITIALIZATION. Loading cannot continue
[23:51:08] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: 
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    FML{8.99.18.1419} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Forge{11.14.1.1419} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    NilCraft{@VERSION@} [Nil Craft] (NilCraft-MC-1.8-0.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
[23:51:08] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: The following problems were captured during this phase
[23:51:08] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Caught exception from NilCraft
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.NilCraft$.preInit(NilCraft.scala:26) ~[NilCraft-MC-1.8-0.1.jar:?]
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.NilCraft.preInit(NilCraft.scala) ~[NilCraft-MC-1.8-0.1.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:537) ~[forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212) ~[forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190) ~[forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1]8.0_45
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119) [LoadController.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:527) [Loader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:246) [FMLClientHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:446) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:356) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:117) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:68) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.class:?]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) ~[Try$.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:67) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:543) ~[ActorSystemImpl.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:110) ~[ActorSystem$.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:92) ~[ActorSystem$.class:?]
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<init>(package.scala:17) ~[package$.class:?]
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<clinit>(package.scala) ~[package$.class:?]
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.11.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:68) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.class:?]
    at scl.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) ~[Try$.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:67) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85) ~[ReflectiveDynamicAccess.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:543) ~[ActorSystemImpl.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:110) ~[ActorSystem$.class:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:92) ~[ActorSystem$.class:?]
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<init>(package.scala:17) ~[package$.class:?]
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<clinit>(package.scala) ~[package$.class:?]
    ... 41 more
[23:51:08] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:663]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Hey, that tickles! Hehehe!

Time: 6/17/15 11:51 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:163)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:529)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:246)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:446)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:356)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.NilCraft$.preInit(NilCraft.scala:26)
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.NilCraft.preInit(NilCraft.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatidAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.preinitializeMods(Loader.java:527)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccla:68)a
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:85)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:543)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:110)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:92)
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<init>(package.scala:17)
    at com.tesract.nilcraft.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 55 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.10.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_45, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 348836872 bytes (332 MB) / 533200896 bytes (508 MB) up to 1908932608 bytes (1820 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.10 FML v8.99.18.1419 Minecraft Forge 11.14.1.1419 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    FML{8.99.18.1419} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    Forge{11.14.1.1419} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.8-11.14.1.1419.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized
    NilCraft{@VERSION@} [Nil Craft] (NilCraft-MC-1.8-0.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Errored
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel Inc.' Version: '2.1 INTEL-10.6.20' Renderer: 'Intel HD Graphics 5000 OpenGL Engine'
[23:51:08] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:663]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# ~/Desktop/forge-1.8-11.14.1.1419-src/eclipse/./crash-reports/crash-2015-06-17_23.51.08-client.txt
:runClient FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.589 secs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

application.conf had:

```
provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
```

cluster isn't part of akka-actor its part of akka-cluster.

I've switched to

```
provider = "akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider"
```

That works now.  The other option is to add akka-cluster to the dependancies list.  If your actually trying to use ClusterActorRefProvider